# pgbackups:restore internal error

Tags: heroku, restore

$heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE "http://........heroku2.dump" --app myapp

!    **Internal server error.**

!    Run `heroku status` to check for known platform issues.

$heroku status

=== Heroku Status

Development: No known issues at this time.

Production:  No known issues at this time.

$Heroku logs --app tcdemo

No entries specific to any of these commands. myapp.herokuapp.com comes up in the browser.

How can I find out the details of Heroku internal server error?